# angularjs http get from json url

Tags: angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have problem with this code I have json data from my asp.net web api. I could not get this data by angularjs. as you can see the the code;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">
<head>
    <title ng-bind="helloAngular"></title>    
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
                var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
                myapp.controller('myController', function ($scope, $htpp){
                    $htpp.get({
                        method:'GET',
                        url:'http://localhost:50972/api/product'})
                        .success(function (response) {
                        $scope.result = response.statusText
                    });
                });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="myController">
        <table border="1">
                <tr ng-repeat="product in response">
                    <td>{{product.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{product.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{product.type}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: what error or data  are you getting in response?  where is your web api code to see what you are returning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some typo errors: instead of `$htpp` use `$http`

```
myapp.controller('myController', function ($scope, $http){
                    $http.get({
                        method:'GET',
                        url:'http://localhost:50972/api/product'})
                        .success(function (response) {
                        $scope.result = response.data;
                    });
                });
```